# High load average: Which processes are waiting in the queue?

Tags: uptime, sar, load-average

I have an Ubuntu server running Redis, which suffers from a high load problem.

## Forensics

### Uptime

```
# uptime
05:43:53 up 19 min,  1 user,  load average: 2.96, 2.07, 1.52
```

### sar

```
# sar -q 
05:24:00 AM       LINUX RESTART

05:25:01 AM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15   blocked
05:35:04 AM         0       116      3.41      2.27      1.20         4
Average:            0       116      3.41      2.27      1.20         4
```

## htop

The CPU is utilization in `htop` is embarrassingly low:
[image]

## top

[image]

## netstat

34 open `redis-server` connections:

```
$ sudo netstat -natp | grep redis-server | wc -l
34
```

[image]

### free

```
$ free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            14          6          8          0          0          2
-/+ buffers/cache:          4         10
Swap:            0          0          0
```

**How do I know which processes are causing the high load, waiting to enter the `Running` state? Is the number of connections too high?**

Comment: You should look at the regular `top` which in my opinion gives a clearer reading.  From what you show, there is most likely I/O bound processes (intensive hard drive or network usage).

Comment: How many CPUs/threads does the server have, why do you consider that number high?

Comment: @Mat:  What is strange and making me curious about what is really running is that the load is near 3 while CPU activity is very low.  I really wonder why someone would post this information asking such a weird question.  If OP is not trolling or faking the `htop` results, then he should provide more details.

Comment: Sure. What other details would help?

Comment: The regular `top` heading would be interesting although I'd actually prefer to see the whole page to get a better perspective of what is running.  I doubt you have secret software which would incriminate you but feel free to hide these names if needed.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Added forensics data, including full-screenshot of `top`.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you ever managed to solve this issue, @AdamMatan ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're seeing the unexpected loadavg because of high iowait.  98.7 in the `wa` section of top shows this.  From your screenshots I see the kworker process is also in uninterruptible sleep (state of D within top) which occurs when a process is waiting for disk I/O to complete.

`vmstat` gives you visibility into the run queue.  Execute `vmstat 1` in typical `sar` fashion for updates every second.

[image]

The r column shows runnable/running processes which the kernel uses to calculate loadavg and the b column shows processes blocked waiting for disk I/O aka uninterruptible sleep.  Processes in b are added to the loadavg calculation, which is how iowait causes mysterious loadavg.

So to answer your question of how to see which procs are causing high loadavg, in your case of iowait, use `top`/`ps` to look for procs in a state of D then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I'm having too many open Redis connections. Investigating, will update here.

Comment: @AdamMatan can you please update the result of investigation here, I am also facing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Linux, unlike most if not all other Unix like OSes, is not only counting processes using a CPU or waiting for a CPU in the run queue as a reference for its load calculation, but also add the number of processes (threads actually)  being in uninterruptible state, i.e. waiting for for a disk or network I/O to complete. The latter are actually idle, i.e. not using the CPU.

There is then probably nothing to worry about your (not so) high load. The processes your are looking for are likely the single threaded `redis` plus transcient kernel threads.